# Should I pin my Python dependencies versions?

Tags: python, dependencies, pip, versioning, semantic-versioning

I am about to release a Python library I've been working on the past few weeks. I've read a lot about Python dependencies but something is not quite clear yet:

Some people pretend you should **never** pin your dependencies versions as it would prevent the users of your library from upgrading those dependencies.

Some other claim that you should **always** pin your dependencies versions as it is the only way of guaranteeing that your release works the way it did when you developed it and to prevent that a breaking change in a dependency wreaks havoc in your library.

I somehow went for an hybrid solution, where I assumed my dependencies used [semantic versioning](http://semver.org/)  and pinned only the major version number (say `somelib >= 2.3.0, < 3`) except when the major version number is `0` (semantic versioning dictates that such versions are to be considered volatile and may break the API even if only the patch number is bumped).

As of now, I'm not sure which way is the best. Is there an official guideline (even a PEP perhaps ?) that dictates the best practice regarding Python dependencies and how to specify them ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should always pin your dependencies as it increases the possibility of safe, repeatable builds, even as time passes.  The pinned versions are your declaration as a package maintainer that you've verified that your code works in a given environment.  This has a nice side effect of preserving your sanity as you won't be inundated with bug reports in which you have to play inspector into every package codependency and system detail.

Users can always choose to ignore the pinned dependency-versions and do so at their own risk.  However, as you release new versions of your library, you should update your dependency versions to take in improvements and bug fixes.

The section of [PEP 426 about Semantic dependencies](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0426/#semantic-dependencies) (Metadata for Python Software Packages ) states:

"Dependency management is heavily dependent on the version identification and specification scheme defined in [PEP 440](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0440/) (PEP 440 - Version Identification and Dependency Specification)."

From this, I infer that the authoritative "best practice" is to version your dependencies, as the relationship of the PEP on packaging is stated to be "heavily dependent" on the versioning details outlined by the related PEP.

Comment: Your inference in the last paragraph is incorrect.  What the quote means is that for dependency management to work correctly, packages must use semantic version numbers that comply with the PEP-specified format.  This does not have anything to do with how tightly or loosely dependencies should be specified.

Comment: The study at [Python Dependency Resolution](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1x_VrNtXCup75qA3glDd2fQOB2TakldwjKZ6pXaAjAfg/) points out a number of problems with pinning, as documented in my answer.

Comment: "The pinned versions are your declaration as a package maintainer that you've verified that your code works in a given environment." -- True, but the problem is that you can only make *one* such declaration when pinning dependencies to very specific versions, when in fact other versions might work equally well (and you might even have verified that).

Comment: if you choose to pin versions, you are supposed to pin them in the end-product, but never in a library; According to http://nvie.com/posts/pin-your-packages/

Comment: You should NOT pin dependencies when you are still developing; in this situation you often want to track changes in important dependencies. Only when releasing you want to pin dependencies.

Comment: "Users can always choose to ignore the pinned dependency-versions and do so at their own risk." - it's pretty hard to work around this as a user. If I want to `pip install a b` and `a` and `b` both pin different, specific versions of library `c`, then how do I install them both?

Answer (score 109):

The reason the two other answers contradict each other is that they're both right (and worth reading), but they apply to different situations.

If you're releasing a library on PyPI, you should declare whatever dependencies you know about, but *not* pin to a specific version. For example, if you know you need `>= 1.2`, but `1.4` is broken, then you can write something like `somepkg >= 1.2, != 1.4`. If one of the things you know is that `somepkg` follows SemVer, then you can add a `< 2`.

If you're building something like a web app that you deploy yourself, then you should pin all of your exact dependencies, and use a service like pyup.io or requires.io to notify you when new versions are released. This way you can stay up to date, while making sure that the versions you deploy are the same as the versions you tested against.

Notice that these two pieces of advice complement each other: it's just a fact that if app A uses library B, then either the author of A or the author of B can pin B's dependencies, but not both. So we have to pick one. The underlying principle here is that this is best done as late as possible, i.e., by the author of A, who can see their whole system; the job of library B is to pass on some useful hints to help A make these decisions. In particular, if all of the libraries that A depends on record exactly what they know about their underlying dependencies, then it's possible for A to make sensible decisions about what to do when they overlap. Like if dependency B depends on `requests >= 1.0, != 1.2`, and dependency C depends on `requests >= 1.1`, then we can guess that 1.1 or 1.3 might be good versions to pin. If dependency B depends on `requests == 1.1` and dependency C depends on `requests == 1.2`, then we're just stuck.

Comment: That's a very lucid explanation that puts the other two answers into proper  perspective. And the advice is probably good not just for Python packages, but any kind of package management that follows something like semver. Easily deserves to be the accepted answer, IMO.

Comment: Pin your direct dependencies not the dependencies of those dependencies. If you don't trust it, then use pip freeze and enjoy updating every single dep.  With good testing of your code, I don' think you need to maintain anything but the direct dependencies in your requirements.txt file. Take a look at mozillas bedrock project, its a django project. I like how they do it.

Comment: @radtek I disagree that in a library you should generally pin even the direct dependencies. You should leave them as loose as possible by the same arguments Nathaniel very clearly presented.

Comment: "*If one of the things you know is that `somepkg` follows SemVer, then you can add a `< 2`*", I am not quite convinced this is good advice. As far as I understood, SemVer does not say that a major version bump implies a breaking change. Semver allows major version bumps even if there is no breaking change. -- Unnecessary upper bounds are a growing annoyance in Python packaging ecosystem.

Comment: Yet if voting for / against these opposing answers is treated as a popularity poll, then **not pinning is twice as popular as pinning** (in Python at least) (24+12 votes against pinning vs. 18+0  for it). I'm assuming for simplicity that everyone voted only once (whereas in practice it can lead to some double-counting in case of two contradicting answers).

Answer (score 24):

Pinning can be problematic and lead to security risks. Especially for a library, as in your case, it can lead to *more* dependency conflicts if it will typically be used in combination with other PyPI packages which themselves will have dependencies.

Why? A detailed study of [Python Dependency Resolution](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1x_VrNtXCup75qA3glDd2fQOB2TakldwjKZ6pXaAjAfg/), after analyzing tens of thousands of PyPI packages and their current rates of dependency conflicts, discusses this issue. It explains that:

> if the distribution is not installed into its own, empty, single-purpose environment, then the likelihood of dependency conflicts is substantially increased if dependency versions are all pinned instead of leaving the ranges flexible.

and notes that **pinning can exacerbate security problems** by interfering with upgrading.

It advises:

> If a project pins dependencies, then it must be prepared to issue a new release every time there is an important release of anything the project depends on directly or indirectly, all the way down the dependency chain.