# When I install django with pipenv, which approach is better?

Tags: python, django, bash, terminal, pipenv

When installing packages and other things in project like django, is declaring a version good or bad?

```
pipenv install django
```

or

```
pipenv install django==3.1.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're developing an application (which I'm assuming you are since you're using Django), it's best practice to pin your dependencies to ensure safe, repeatable builds and that future releases work when you developed it. Typically this is done in a `requirements.txt` file, which can be automatically generated via `pip freeze > requirements.txt`.

If you're developing a library, it's still recommended to pin the dependencies, but with looser constraints (e.g. `~=3.1.0` or `>=3.1.0` instead of `==3.1.0`).

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28509481/should-i-pin-my-python-dependencies-versions) for further discussions on this topic.

Answer (score 0):

Except you need a particular version for some particular reason, declaring the version before performing your pip install is not really necessary. Usually, the one automatically installed would work just as fine.

If you still prefer installing specific versions, there is nothing wrong with that.